# I am using readline to input a number for a project, but whatever i type, it appears twice, i.e. if i press 1, it comes out 11, etc

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this is probably a stupid question, but i am just starting out with coding, and any help will be appreciated. i am using the first part for calling  my functions, and the bottom one to send it. it is incomplete, i know, but i just want to figure out why it's entering a double digit.

```
var main = require("./toDoListMain");
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin,process.stdout);

console.log("1. Add a list"+'\n' + "2. Select list" + '\n' + "3. Remove a list" + '\n'+ "4. View lists "+ '\n' + "5. Exit");
```

depending on a person's answer earlier, this will decide which function to send.

```
rl.question("What do you want to do?", function(firstAnswer){

    if(firstAnswer == 1){
        addList();
    }
    else if(firstAnswer == 2){
        showList();
        select();

    }
    else if(firstAnswer == 3){
        selectList();
        removeList();


    }
    else if (firstAnswer == 4){
        showList();


    }

    else {
        rl.close;
        process.exit();





    }


});
```

//start of the second part

```
    var readline = require('readline');


    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout});




    var toDoList = [];

    var list = {

         addName : function(name){
            rl.question("What is the list's name?", function(answer){
                    var listName = answer;
                    console.log("List's name: " + listName);
                    toDoList = toDoList.concat(listName);






            })},

                    //console.log(animals.push('cows'));
                        //console.log(numLists.push(listName));

         selectList : function(list){

            console.log("You chose 2"); 
            console.log(toDoList);
            rl.question("Which list do you pick? 1-"+ toDoList.length, chosenList);


            },
             removeList : function(remove){

            console.log("You chose 3"); 

                },

                     showList : function(show){
                        console.log("You chose 4");
                        console.log(toDoList);          
                    },

                     goOut : function(quit){
                    console.log("You chose 5");
                    rl.close();             
                    process.exit(); 

                    }
    }


        exports.app = list;
```

Comment: What do you mean its "entering a double digit"?

Comment: i ask a question and the output in the console is: 
1. Add a list 2. Select list
3. Remove a list
4. View lists
5. Exit   
then when i want to enter a number, it comes out twice, e.g. if i type 1, it comes out 11, if i type a, it prints aa, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a repeated entry because you are creating a second readline interface in the second part i.e., you are calling `readline.createInterface` twice in your application.

To solve your problem, remove the additional call to `readline.createInterface`.